# Convert XAML Window to Bitmap

Tags: c#, xaml, bitmap

I have a simple XAML like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="blabla.MyView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="myUserControl">
 <Grid Name="myGrid" Background="White">
    <TextBlock Name="myTextBlock"/>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now I'd like to create a new view in the background by using this xaml. After this, I'd like to change the controls (or maybe add some controls by myself), save it to a Bitmap and assign it to the Clipboard (just to see the output). I would have tried it like this:

```
MyView view = new MyView();
view.myTextBlock.Text = "TEST";

Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(view);
DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
{
    VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(view);
    ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(), bounds.Size));
}
RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)view.ActualWidth, (int)view.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

bmp.Render(dv);

PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetImage(pngImage.Frames[0]);
```

Unfortunately, the Size of the `view` is not being changed. Trying to set a hard coded width/height by produces a black image/bitmap.

How can I create a simple Bitmap out of a XAML?

Comment: To clearify: You want to render a view, that has not being loaded?

Comment: @Malior what do you mean with loaded? I thought it's being loaded by calling `MyView()`? I'd like to create a XAML in the background and change the text (or other controls). The view, which is not being "loaded" (=> the user can't see it on his screen), should dynamically be created and then I'd like to create a Bitmap of the view. So normally in my example I want to have a bitmap of MyView, which should display an image with my TextBlock and the text "TEST".

Comment: Im am not 100% sure, but I believe that it is black, as the view is not loaded. Try to .Show() the view before rendering to see if it's working.

Comment: MyView has no method `show()`. I've done the following now: `var window = new System.Windows.Window();                 window.Content = view;
                window.Show();
                window.Close();`  
This works fine and it's updating my Height/Width and everything :) It would be better without show(), but this workaround works for now, so thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the comment to official answer. However, I see that this solution is not the most elegant one. General thing is, that the window, resp. view, will result in black area when rendered while it is not visible/redered itself by showing it anyhow.

The workarround would be to show this view (as you wrote, but in Window).
Small idea doing this, move the window out of visible screen to avoid flickering. 
example:

```
        var v = new MainWindow();
        v.Top = -10000; // far away
        v.Left = -10000; // far away
        v.Show();
        // .. do rendering
        v.Close();
```